# In firebase I get error of FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17048 "Invalid token. in ios development." How to solve it?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using firebase OTP authentication in my app.I pass my number to PhoneAuthProvider method of firebase but after that give a error of Invalid token in all device except my device.
How to solve this error?

> Error look like:

```
(Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17048 "Invalid token." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid token., error_name=INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL})
```

Answer (score 6):

Upload APNs Auth Key in firebase iOS app configuration

Comment: firebase given this suggestion : Open firebase >go to console>select your project> click on setting icon (left side)>select project seting>select cloud messaging>go down "iOS app configuration" part> upload APNs Authentication Key.

Comment: did you get the result..?

Comment: I have the APNs Auth Key uploaded already, but am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Have solved this issue ? Because I was getting OPTs but suddenly I am getting Invalid token.